# SQL using count value as offset

Tags: mysql, count, max, offset

This is a follow on from another question i made

I have this query that counts all the records up to a certain point i choose whcih works fine

```
SELECT count(*)FROM news WHERE id < 18
```

this query gives me a count of 7

I am now having problems with the offset which would be the result of the above query

I tried using this query

```
SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7,1
```

but i get id number 13 instead of 18

The ids i should have is 2, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23

I have tried using order by id desc in the count query which does give a different result but still wrong id displayed

Comment: The possibility is that you dont need to use LIMIT&OFFSET at all. You should explain further what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need it for paging the results in php but i have it working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see a problem here: You order the result by `id DESC` which means your result is ordered by other way around and 8th value(0..7) is 13.

Try sorting it by `ASC` then it will give you 18

Comment: I managed to fix it by going the other way and looking for freater than then just minus 1 off the result to get me the right id